# If line contains pattern, print variable to column

Tags: sed, variable, gawk

I have the file `DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-1-distance-1.coordLog`:

```
 REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.944776     0.190651     1.602108   |r| =     1.869679
  r(2,5)           =    -0.693580    -0.927860    -1.000974   |r| =     1.530989
  r(2,8)           =     1.618580     0.570765    -0.688275   |r| =     1.849134

 REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.945905     0.187745     1.601950   |r| =     1.869821
  r(2,5)           =    -0.692409    -0.928976    -1.001505   |r| =     1.531483
  r(2,8)           =     1.618487     0.572023    -0.688769   |r| =     1.849626

 REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.946708     0.186226     1.601724   |r| =     1.869881
  r(2,5)           =    -0.691970    -0.929421    -1.002033   |r| =     1.531900
  r(2,8)           =     1.618395     0.572685    -0.688576   |r| =     1.849678
```

I want to read every line in the file and if it contains patter `r(1,5)`, I want to print the value after `|r| =`. So far I've written the following code.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -o errexit
    set -o nounset
    set -o pipefail


  exec 0<"DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-1-distance-1.coordLog"
     while read -r line
     do
     for j in $(seq 0 2)
     do
     if [[ "$line" == *"r(1,5)"* ]] ; then
             dist1=$(gawk 'BEGIN{FS="|r| ="} {print $2}' | tr -s " ")
        elif [[ "$line" == *"r(2,5)"* ]] ; then
                dist2=$(gawk 'BEGIN{FS="|r| ="} {print $2}' | tr -s " ")
        elif [[ "$line" == *"r(2,8)"* ]] ; then
                dist3=$(gawk 'BEGIN{FS="|r| ="} {print $2}' | tr -s " ")
     fi


     printf "%-3f %-3f %-3f %-3f\n" "1.$j" "$dist1" "$dist2" "$dist3"

     done
     done>DEMLIR_task.txt
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
dist1: unbound variable
```

It doesn't get to the line with `"1.$j"` but I know that it will also give an error with 1.0.

I also tried `sed` to get what I want, which looks like this:

```
sed -n '/r(1,5)/p' DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-1-distance-1.coordLog> new
sed -i 's/^.*|r| =//' new
```

This prints the values after `|r| =` in a new file, and considering I have to do the same thing for 2 other conditions as you can see in the if statement I will end up with too many unwanted files. I don't want that.

I want the first way to work. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I want to print 0,1,2 to the first column, the distance for `r(1,5)` to the second column, `r(2,5)` to the third column and `r(2,8)` to the fourth column in a new file called `DEMLIR_task.txt` . And I want to do it without creating new files or changing the original file. The output I want is this:

```
0 1.869679 1.530989 1.849134
1 1.869821 1.531483 1.849626
2 1.869881 1.531900 1.849678
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L! I recommend to you to solve your task using `awk` only. It's more convenient in this situation.

Comment: `gawk` is GNU `awk`. In many Linux distros `awk` and `gawk` is the same. You read file line by line using bash. I recommend to you to read file using only `awk`/`gawk`. `awk` supports `if-then` constructions. See [man 1 gawk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html) for details.

Comment: I've just post an possible answer. Is it correct for your situation?

Comment: Your desired output does not match the description. For example, the r(1,5) you say must go to column #2, whereas it is shown as row #1. Similarly for the rest as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `sed`, `echo` and `tr`:

```
$ se () { echo -n "$1 "; sed -n 's/\s*r('"$2"').*|r| =\s\+//p' DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-1-distance-1.coordLog | tr '\n' ' '; echo; }
$ se 0 1,5; se 1 2,5; se 2 2,8
0 1.869679 1.869821 1.869881
1 1.530989 1.531483 1.531900
2 1.849134 1.849626 1.849678

# using a for-loop
cnt=0; for i in 1,5 2,5 2,8; do se $((cnt++)) $i; done
```

To write the output to a file, you can use

```
{ se 0 1,5; se 1 2,5; se 2 2,8; } > DEMLIR_task.txt
```

If this was the wrong order, you can use this snippet using `sed`, `paste` and `printf`:

```
$ se () { sed -n 's/\s*r('"$1"').*|r| =\s\+//p' DEMLIR-GEO_OPT-1-distance-1.coordLog; }
$ paste -d' ' <(printf '%s\n' 0 1 2) <(se 1,5) <(se 2,5) <(se 2,8)
0 1.869679 1.530989 1.849134
1 1.869821 1.531483 1.849626
2 1.869881 1.531900 1.849678

# using a for-loop and temp files, first column starts with 1 instead of 0
rm -f tmp.*; cnt=0; for i in 1,5 2,5 2,8; do se $i > tmp.$((cnt++)); done; paste -d ' ' tmp.* | cat -n
```

Comment: Is there a way to go through the arguments for `se` in a for loop?

Comment: Added. The second example is using temp files and `cat -n` for the first column as it's difficult to know the number of items (rows) beforehand. So the numbering starts with 1. `awk` is far more elegant for such things.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution in `awk` only.
I've created an `prg.awk`:

```
BEGIN { j=0; }
{
    if ( $1 == "r(1,5)" )
    {
        dist1=$8;
    }
    if ( $1 == "r(2,5)" )
    {
        dist2=$8;
    }
    if ( $1 == "r(2,8)")
    {
        dist3=$8;
        print j": "dist1" "dist2" "dist3;
        ++j;
    }
}
```

Content of `file.txt`:

```
yurijs-MacBook-Pro:bash yurij$ cat ./file.txt
REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.944776     0.190651     1.602108   |r| =     1.869679
  r(2,5)           =    -0.693580    -0.927860    -1.000974   |r| =     1.530989
  r(2,8)           =     1.618580     0.570765    -0.688275   |r| =     1.849134

 REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.945905     0.187745     1.601950   |r| =     1.869821
  r(2,5)           =    -0.692409    -0.928976    -1.001505   |r| =     1.531483
  r(2,8)           =     1.618487     0.572023    -0.688769   |r| =     1.849626

 REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA

  Distance vector r(i,j) between the atom i and j in ANGSTROM

  r(1,5)           =     0.946708     0.186226     1.601724   |r| =     1.869881
  r(2,5)           =    -0.691970    -0.929421    -1.002033   |r| =     1.531900
  r(2,8)           =     1.618395     0.572685    -0.688576   |r| =     1.849678
```

Run the program:

```
yurijs-MacBook-Pro:bash yurij$ awk -f prg.awk ./file.txt
0: 1.869679 1.530989 1.849134
1: 1.869821 1.531483 1.849626
2: 1.869881 1.531900 1.849678
```

Comment: Okay now I see what you said by use `awk` only. Thank you very much!  This was only a segment of the code so I cannot use it directly but I can define something like `awk_result` and with a little modification I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message `dist1: unbound variable` because you have set the `nounset` shell option.  You are then using the `dist1` variable before it is set.

---

```awk
/REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA/ { ++n; m = 0 }

$6 == "|r|" { r[n,++m] = $NF }

END {
    for (j = 1; j <= m; ++j) {
        $0 = j - 1
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            $(i + 1) = r[i,j]

        print
    }
}
```

(redirect the output with e.g. `awk ... >DEMLIR_task.txt` to save it in a new file)

The data comes in sections, each section starting with a line saying `REQUESTED STRUCTURE DATA` and containing a number of records.  The records may be found by looking for the string `|r|` in the 6th field.

The above `awk` program outputs the numbers collected from the last field of each record within a section in columns, each line preceded by a counter.  It assumes that there may conceivably be any number of records for each section (`m` in the code) and that there may be any number of sections in the input data (`n` in the code).

Testing:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
0 1.869679 1.869821 1.869881
1 1.530989 1.531483 1.531900
2 1.849134 1.849626 1.849678
```